# Why are my tires squeaking?

Tags: tire

My tires starting squeaking just as move off on level ground several times. It didn't happen moving uphill. The air temperature is mild. It squeaks several times in row. I just got my tires inflated today. Is it indicative of a significant problem?

Comment: Are the tyres brand new?   Is the ground surface a smooth or painted concrete ?

Comment: Are you sure it’s the tyres? Something has to rub against something else to make a squeaky sound. The only way I can get my tyres to squeak is when I make a very tight turn on smooth ground (e.g. smooth tile).

Comment: The tires can rub against the rim. The tires are new less than five years. The surface is the mixed tiles and bitumen that is the pavement.

Comment: Is this a mountain bike or cyclocross bike with super low tyre pressure? How wide are the tyres and what pressure are you using?

Comment: First, make sure the tires aren't rubbing against the fame.  Then check the joint between tire and rim and make sure the tires are seated evenly.

Comment: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/62283/my-new-bicycle-skids-laterally-especially-in-the-wet-what-can-i-do-about-it   This bicycle

Answer (score 1):

I had this once on a bike that had not been used for several years.  The rubber compound had deteriorated and gone a bit plasticky on the outside.

If this is the case, the safest course of action is to buy new tyres.

In my case they were MTB tyres, so what I did was ride them very cautiously on gravel (no traffic) for a couple of rides - this seemed to wear off the damaged outer rubber and restore adequate performance.

I would probably not be willing to risk doing the same thing on road tyres where grip is much more safety critical.

Comment: I was under the impression that most new quality tyres squeal on the right surface. Once they wear in a bit they are usually quieter

Comment: @Noise new tyres have a "mold release" agent on them to help with getting the tyre out of the vulcanising press.  This wears off after 5-10 km of riding, but that first ride can be sketchy in the damp and squeaky in the dry.  Andy's talking about tyres that have gone hard with ozone/UV exposure and are not gripping well.